# $\mathcal{J}-$ trivial elements

Tags: semigroups, greens-relations

What does it mean by saying that

> … idempotents are $\mathcal{J}-$ trivial.

Indeed, by searching old docs and this [one](https://www.irif.fr/~jep/Logiciels/Semigroupe/Doc.pdf), we see that:

> A semigroup $S$ is $\mathcal{J}-$ trivial if two elements of $S$ which are $\mathcal{J}-$ equivalent are equal.

Is the following correct:

> $a,b∈ S$ which $[a]_{\mathcal{J}}=[b]_{\mathcal{J}}$ are $\mathcal{J}-$ trivial in $S$ iff $a=b$.

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semigroup is indeed $\mathcal{J}$-trivial is the Green's relation $\mathcal{J}$ is the equality. However, I do not understand the expressions "$a$ and $b$ are $\mathcal{J}$-trivial" and "idempotents are $\mathcal{J}$-trivial". Do you mean "the semigroup generated by the idempotents is $\mathcal{J}$-trivial" or something like that?

Comment: May I ask you: Is there any of your old works in which you did some facts related to ideals of a semigroup?

Comment: Semigroup ideals are a very basic notion in semigroup theory as well as the Green's preorder $\leqslant_\mathcal{J}$ and the Green's equivalence $\mathcal{J}$. They appear in every textbook in semigroup theory and they are used all the time (including in my own research). But you should start with the notions of minimal and $0$-minimal ideals, on which there are classical (but nontrivial) results. This material is covered in most books on semigroups.